# String Matching is not happening between two time In JSP

Tags: java, date

Initial time=22:00:00,final time=23:59:59.
If the current time is, let's say 23:00:00 then I will get the success message otherwise error message will be shown. And I am comparing this time with the system time.

My code:

```
//retrieving the system time in string format
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String s=sdfDate.format(date);

//Initial and final predefined time 
String ten ="22:00:00";
String twelve ="23:59:59";

//comparing with the system time
try{
if(s.compareTo("twelve")<0 && s.compareTo("ten")>0 ){
out.print("success");
}else{
out.print("failed");
}
}catch(Exception l){
System.out.println(l.toString());
}
```

I tried to check it when the system time was 23:45:00. I also confirmed the time by printing `out.print(""+s);`. But I got the failed message. I don't know my loop is working or not.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compare a string containing a time (e.g. `"23:00:00"`) with the string `"ten"` or `"twelve"`.  That won't do anything sensible.

Comment: yes comparing with the two predefined times. Then what needs to be done here?

Comment: You are **not** comparing to the two variables you defined. You are comparing to string literals.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're comparing hours, don't use strings, use a proper type.

In Java you have:

- Java >= 8: `java.time.LocalTime`
- Java <= 7: `org.threeten.bp.LocalTime` (from external lib: http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)

In both you can do:

```
LocalTime ten = LocalTime.parse("22:00:00");
LocalTime twelve = LocalTime.parse("23:59:59");

// current time
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();

// compare
if (now.isBefore(twelve) && now.isAfter(ten)) {
    // succcess
}
```

To get the current time, you could also use the `now` method with a timezone (example: `LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))`), if you need the time at some specific place (`now()` without arguments will use the JVM default timezone).

Transforming the strings to a type that represents the data you're working with is much more reliable. Also note that this API makes the code much easier and more readable, with meaningful methods names such as `isAfter` and `isBefore`.

Comparing strings might work, but using the proper types works even better.

Comment: This is also working, a better and lot easier way to compare the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(s.compareTo(twelve) < 0 && s.compareTo(ten) > 0)
```

By putting quotes around `twelve` and `ten`, you're comparing to the strings `"twelve"` and `"ten"`, and not referencing the variables `twelve` and `ten` that you defined ealier in the program.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it's working now.Quotes are responsible for it.again thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When an answer works, please accept it as the answer (click on the checkmark).  "Thanks" comments are polite but unnecessary.  Also, be sure to "upvote" (click up-arrow to the left of) comments that were helpful.